# Avery 5168 Labels in RDLC

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I am currently working on creating an RDLC report for the Avery 5168 labels. The report is being created in Visual Studio 2010 and the will be for mailing labels. The report should show the addresses 2x2 on each page of the report. I have tried several different solutions with no success.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you post an answerable question: " I have tried several different solutions with no success" - and they were?

Comment: OK...How do you created an mailing label report, using the Avery 5168 format? That's a question. I have a group of users that have a FormattedAddress property. I simply need to figure out if there is a control in VS 2010 that can accommodate grouping left and down. I tried the Table (Tablix) control, but can't seem to figure out how to repeat records right and down.

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar (I used Avery 5163) to this recently and it works great.

First I went to Avery's site and downloaded the template for MS Word for the labels I am using.

Next I chopped up the xml in that template so it would be easier to use from the code, basically I just stripped what wasn't needed and divided it into sections.

In the code, I then made several strings to store each xml section, such as the xml header, Column 1 Address start, Column 1 Address end, and so on... After that I simply looped through my data while adding the xml formatting strings as necessary and writing to one main string.

Finally I wrote that main string to a file and sent to user as a download.

I don't have time at the moment but if you would like I could add the code I used as an example for you.

Comment: Just noticed how old this question is, if anyone still has an interest let me know and I'll get a more detailed answer.